# Render React Component Inside of Highcharts Graph

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I'd like to be able to render a React Component inside of a HighCharts Graph. I'd like to render the component DatePicker inside my HighCharts Graph, rather than being above it like it currently is? I'm using the HighCharts Official React Wrapper, and this is what my code looks like:

```
function Graph(props) {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date('1969-11-19 PST'));
  const [bx, setBx] = useState([]);
  const [by, setBy] = useState([]);
  const [bz, setBz] = useState([]);

  async function getData(table, year, month, day) {
    ...
}

  useEffect(() => {
   ...
  }, [startDate])

  var options = {
    chart: {
      events: {
        load: function() {
          this.showLoading();
          setTimeout(this.hideLoading.bind(this), 2000);
        }
      }
    },
    lang: {
      noData: "Awaiting for data"
    },
    rangeSelector: {
      inputEnabled: false,
      buttons: [
        {
          type: 'all',
          text: '1d',
          title: 'View 1 Day'
        },
        {
        type: 'minute',
        count: 10,
        text: '10m',
        title: 'View 10 minutes'
        },
        {
          type: 'minute',
          count: 1,
          text: '1m',
          title: 'View 1 minutes'
        },
        {
          type: 'second',
          count: 30,
          text: '30s',
          title: 'View 30 seconds'
        },
    ]
    },
    chart: {
      zoomType: 'x'
    },
    title: {
      text: props.title
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime'
    },
    time: {
      timezoneOffset: 8*60
    },
    series: [
      {
        marker: {
          enabled: true,
          radius: 2
        },
        color: 'red',
        name: 'Bx',
        pointStart: startDate.getTime(),
        pointInterval: 1000,
        data: bx // data has to be [x, y] pairs
      },
      {
        marker: {
          enabled: true,
          radius: 2
        },
        color: 'blue',
        name: 'By',
        pointStart: startDate.getTime(),
        pointInterval: 1000,
        data: by
      },
      {
        marker: {
          enabled: true,
          radius: 2
        },
        color: 'green',
        name: 'Bz',
        pointStart: startDate.getTime(),
        pointInterval: 1000,
        data: bz
      }
    ]
  }

  const isValidDate = (date) => {
    date.getTime();
    const origDate = new Date('1969-11-19 PST');
    const finalDate = new Date('1970-04-03 PST');
    console.log("GET DATE", date.getTime()) // getting number day of month
    const bool = origDate.getTime() <= date.getTime() && date.getTime() <= finalDate.getTime();
    return bool;
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <DatePicker 
        selected={startDate}
        filterDate={isValidDate}
        onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
      />
      <HighchartsReact
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        constructorType={'stockChart'}
        options={options}
        />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

[image: image of current output]

I see this example from the HighCharts React Official Wrapper Github, but I'm still a bit confused by it and am wondering if I could simply do the same thing with a functional component. https://codesandbox.io/s/1o5y7r31k3

I've made a codesandbox of my code here https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-moon-y8guc

Comment: Hi @matthewcy, Yes, you can use the same approach with react portal and a functional component. It would be great if you could create a live example with your current code.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've created a CodeSandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-moon-y8guc

Comment: Thanks for the example! The simplest solution is to just position the date picker on the chart by CSS. Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-https-zqls-zqlsm?file=/src/App.js